# Ignore unsafe html in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using textangular directive for angular text editor
I have a string in database as:

```
State of Ticket: #TicketState            
                <br>  <br/>
       Ticket Url: <#LinkTextStart>Click</#LinkTextEnd>
        <br>  <br/>
```

I want this value to be displayed in text editor

```
 <text-angular  ng-bind-htm="html" ></text-angular>
```

when I use ng-bind-html it ignores `</#LinkTextEnd>` and displays all the remaning string without text editor

and when I use ng-model then it opens empty text editor

my requirement is to show `Ticket Url: <#LinkTextStart>Click</#LinkTextEnd>` inside text editor

Comment: what is `text-angular`? is it a component?

Comment: You want to escape the `<br>` tags and convert them into newlines, but not the `<#LinkTextStart>Click</#LinkTextEnd>` part is it ?

Comment: text-angular is a directive for text editor @Aravind

Comment: yes you are absolutely right @PrabodhM

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the html as trusted for security reasons. You can use a filter.

```
app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function toTrustedHtml($sce) {
    return function(text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);
```

and use it like

```
<text-angular  ng-bind-html="html | to_trusted" ></text-angular>
```