# 'ng-bind-html-unsafe' doesn't display anything

Tags: angularjs, json, object, ng-bind-html, ngsanitize

I'm displaying a string that has HTML code in it from the JSON.
Please check the 'Name' property in the 2nd object.

However, when I use 'ng-bind-html-unsafe' it doesn't display anything.

I've used ngSanitize as well.

Could you please help me figure out what's wrong with my code?

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.card = [{
    Name: "New Year Celebration",
    Description: "",
    Venue: "",
    StartDate: "Fri Dec 29 2017 23:30:00 GMT+0530",
    EndDate: "Sat Dec 30 2017 00:30:00 GMT+0530",
    EventID: "1"
  }, {
    Name: "&lt;P&gt;25th Anniversary Celebration&lt;/P&gt;",
    Description: "25th Anniversary Celebration of organization",
    Venue: "Auditorium",
    StartDate: "Wed May 31 2017 17:30:00 GMT+0530",
    EndDate: "Wed May 31 2017 20:30:00 GMT+0530",
    EventID: "2"
  }, {
    Name: "Annual Day",
    Description: "",
    Venue: "",
    StartDate: "Fri Oct 13 2017 14:30:00 GMT+0530",
    EndDate: "Fri Oct 13 2017 17:30:00 GMT+0530",
    EventID: "3"
  }];
  
  $scope.trustAsHtml = function(html) {
 return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  }
  $scope.add = function(eventObj) {
  $scope.eventID= this.eventObj.EventID;
  $scope.startDate= this.eventObj.StartDate;
    $scope.endDate= this.eventObj.EndDate;
    $scope.venue= this.eventObj.Venue;
    $scope.subject= this.eventObj.Name;
    $scope.result= this.eventObj.Description;
  //console.log(this);
    $scope.icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nDTSTART:" + $scope.startDate +"\nDTEND:" + $scope.endDate +"\nLOCATION:" + $scope.venue + "\nSUMMARY:" + $scope.subject + "\nDESCRIPTION:"+ $scope.result +"\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";
 window.open("data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape($scope.icsMSG),"_self");
  };
}]);
```

```css
.event {
  height: 150px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.5/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="eventObj in card" class="event">
  Subject: <span ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(eventObj.Name)"></span>
  <br /><br /> 
  Venue:<span>{{eventObj.Venue}}</span>
  <br /><br /> 
  Date:<span>{{eventObj.StartDate | date:'fullDate'}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  <button ng-click="add(eventObj.EventID)">Add to Outlook</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tell us what error your network console tells you. Something like where its blocked from.

Comment: Oh and don´t forget to disable any adblocker or it will fail to load anyway

Comment: I update ny answer. Here is the working demo. https://plnkr.co/edit/sFhaSJ2Ir9PYUObdtcnj?p=preview

Comment: @sunny is the updated answer resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Angular 1.6.x and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been deprecated long ago.  You can use:`ng-bind-html`

```
<div ng-bind-html="eventObj.Name"></div>
```

Note: In your controller, inject the `$sce`,

Edit 1:
     Add this method inside your controller:

Filter:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return function(text) {
         var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, "text/html");
         var   rval= doc.documentElement.textContent;
        console.log(rval)
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(rval)
    };
}]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="eventObj in card" class="event">
  Subject: <span ng-bind-html="eventObj.Name|to_trusted"></span>
  <br /><br />  
  Venue:<span>{{eventObj.Venue}}</span>
  <br /><br />  
  Date:<span>{{eventObj.StartDate | date:'fullDate'}}</span>
  <br /><br />
  <button ng-click="add(eventObj.EventID)">Add to Outlook</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/sFhaSJ2Ir9PYUObdtcnj?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!  But it works partially! Please check the updated code in the snippet above.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839390/ignore-unsafe-html-in-angular/44841269#44841269) . You need to set untrusted html as trusted.

Comment: It doesn't work. May be I'm using that incorrectly. Could you please help me?

Comment: Okay. checking the issue

Comment: I guess it is because of the multiple special characters '&lt;' and '&gt;' wrapped around the p tag.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. If you replace thet with html tag it works fine

Comment: But the JSON am receiving is in the format which I've used here. Hence the problem!

Comment: Yeah. I guess this is limitation. You can raise this isue on docs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148772/discussion-between-ved-and-sunny).